# How to apply Maximum Entropy principle to classify a continuous data set?

Tags: classification, maximum-entropy

Maximum entropy classifier is mostly used for Natural Language Processing, in which the datas are discrete. I learned the formalism from the paper *A maximum entropy approach to natural language processing* and understood most of it.

My question is,
how to apply the Maximum Entropy principle to do the classification on a continuous data set?

I am asking for some sources where I can learn the formalism, not the software packages.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but what is a continuous dataset?

Comment: @gregory_britten , the value of the features are real floating number. Maybe there are some better phrases, sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found this paper,

*[1] D. Yu, L. Deng, and A. Acero, Pattern Recognit. Lett. 30, 1295–1300 (2009).*

That is exactly what I need.